# while setting flutter project , I get error message Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org

Tags: ssl, flutter, get

When I'd like to create new flutter project File, I got error Message,

I tried to set environment variable 'http_proxy' and 'https_proxy'
but, It doesn't work. Is there a ssl setting in flutter or dart pub?

```
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
Running "flutter pub get" in test33...
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 4 in 8 seconds...
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 5 in 16 seconds...
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 6 in 32 seconds...
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 7 in 64 seconds...
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
```

Comment: It seems you are missing the `cupertino_icons` package in your `pubspec.yaml` file.
Check the `pubspec.yaml` find the `cupertino_icons` package, if there is not any package with that name, put this `cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2` and call in your terminal `flutter packages get`

Comment: this project is executed well , when I execute it at my home. When I execute in company, I got these messages. is there a way to setting ssl in flutter?